# Behavior of HDFS High Availability

Tags: hadoop, high-availability

How does [distributed copy](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html) (`distcp`) work between two clusters when NameNode (NN) fails in High Availability (HA) configuration.

Will that job fail due to different IP address of name node and the standby node?

Answer (score 0):

Yashwanth,
In an HA Hadoop cluster, it is not recommended to use active name node in the distcp commands. A simple answer to your question is Yes, if you hardcode Namenode IP or DNS in the distcp command. In an HA hadoop cluster you need to use cluster name in of IP in the distcp command.